# issues with jquery mobile navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a navbar with two items and when I load it first time It is working fine. But when I goback and come again I am facing issues. The first navbar gets highlighted even if the content that was displayed was second items content.Below is my code.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="tabs">
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#fragment-1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fragment-1" style="color:white" >
<ul id="fragment-1ul">
<li>test3<li>
<li>test4<li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fragment-2" style="color:white" >
<ul id="fragment-2ul">
<li>test1<li>
<li>test2<li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add/Remove the ui-state-persist class when link is clicked:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="tabs">
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a onclick="navItemClick(this);" href="#fragment-1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">one</a></li>
<li><a onclick="navItemClick(this);" href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fragment-1" style="color:white" >
<ul id="fragment-1ul">
<li>test3<li>
<li>test4<li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="fragment-2" style="color:white" >
<ul id="fragment-2ul">
<li>test1<li>
<li>test2<li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function navItemClick(obj){

                $("ul a").removeClass("ui-state-persist");
                $(obj).addClass("ui-state-persist");

    }
     </script>
```

Comment: The problem is when I go back and come to the screen I am facing this issue.but for the first time it works fine. Say example if am in first tab and then I go back and coming back to this page the highlighted one and content will be same. Now I press the second tab and then press back button .now if I go back to the same page the highlighted will be first and content shown will be second